# False excessive disk usage, how to explain DF-system and DF-docker contradiction?

Tags: docker, disk-access

At Linux server I checked disk usage by `df`  command and obtained big `/var/lib/docker`  usage

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4078144        0   4078144   0% /dev
tmpfs             817484    82900    734584  11% /run
/dev/vda1      162421080 93727736  68676960  58% /
tmpfs            4087412       96   4087316   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            4087412        0   4087412   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15        106858     3426    103433   4% /boot/efi
none           162421080 93727736  68676960  58% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/7fe...
tmpfs             817484        0    817484   0% /run/user/0
```

so, seems that docker (that have images with no database and no big lib or big dataset) *is consuming all my disk with some trash*, is it? ... And, if is it, how to clean?

But seems that the real problem is not "to clean", but to monitoring my disk usage with **reliable information**, *I need to explain contradiction*, **how to explain?**

---

Note: PostgreSQL database is external (at env not dockered), the only image in use is [PostgREST](https://hub.docker.com/r/postgrest/postgrest/). As @MagdKudama suggested,  `docker system df`  result is:

```
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              1                   1                   112.7MB             0B (0%)
Containers          2                   1                   0B                  0B
Local Volumes       0                   0                   0B                  0B
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

So, this enhances the contradiction, Linux `df` command say other thing, (now using `df -h` to  human comparison)

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
none            155G   90G   66G  58% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/7fe...
```

---

PS: thanks to  @MagdKudama and [this tutorial](https://blog.softwaremill.com/how-to-keep-your-docker-installation-clean-98a74eb7e7b3) that explained 50% of the problem, now I really can say "with 100% of conviction" that it is a contradiction to be explained, by a Ubuntu 18 LTS bug or by my wrong interpretation of `df`  information,
 *(none Filesystem) Mounted on `/var/lib/docker`*.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have old images in Docker. You can use commands like https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/ to remove unused images, old ones...

You can also run https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/, which will remove unused data (networks, unused images, build cache...).

For more detailed information about disk usage on Docker, you can check the command https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/.

Comment: I do (with no stop) command `docker image prune  -a` and in fact it deleted images, it say *"Total reclaimed space: 243.9MB"*... It is nothing, the `df`  command shows the same.

Comment: You can also try https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/. Be careful and read the docs before executing it. Another question would be how many running containers do you have in your system?

Comment: There are a way to test  if it is a `df` bug, a false attribution to docker usage, perhaps stopping all and checking again `df`?

Comment: Please  show all "how many" commands, so I can show  result in the question body

Comment: I added some extra information for you on the answer body @PeterKrauss

Comment: Thanks (!), I add to question Notes the result of     docker df, that show no relevant disk usage (perfect is the expected!)... So there are a Linux `df` bug?  The good question perhaps is "Why Linux `df ` command say that Docker is using all disk?"